# How to organize custom caching in IIS module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis

I'm trying to develop sophisticated caching for my ASP.net application. However due to lack of comprehensive documentation the task turned to more complex assignment than it supposed to be.

I have created IIS module that subscribes to `HttpApplication` and suppose do make work done. The code is below:

```
namespace Cache
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web;

    public class Control : IHttpModule
    {
        #region Public Methods

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.ResolveRequestCache += onResolveRequestCache;
            context.UpdateRequestCache+= onUpdateRequestCache;
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        private void onResolveRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

            // Get cached response body and fire response            
        }

        private void onUpdateRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

            // Put response body to cache
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
}
```

However I faced with following obstacles: It's not clear how to break execution pipeline if object was found in cache. Both methods I discovered: `HttpApplication.Context.Response.End()` and `HttpApplication.Context.Response.Flush()` have their own disadvantages, like the need to manually set all headers or firing all following events in the execution pipeline, even if they are not needed.

Is there any recommendation how to fill `HttpApplication.Context.Response` body with information received from cache provider and how to set correct headers (more or less automatically, maybe cache them selectively too?) and how to correctly skip execution pipeline steps to achieve best application performance.

Comment: Its not very clear that what exactly you want to achieve by handling these events? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @PankajKapare, I want to save my response to Redis based cache and retrieve it afterwards.

Comment: Looks like you want to plug-in custom output cache store. If that is case then here are links that may help you. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers   and   https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Caching.Output/

Answer (score 1):

Whole approach I was considering was incorrect.

The custom caching task should not be solved as IIS module, but as Custom Cache Provider.

The most documented example how to create such solution, I have found in following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

However, it's not answering on question how to control cache behavior if you're working with compiled ASP.NET application and not able to inject some code into controllers.

And if sophisticated and aggressive caching should be performed, in this case the custom module for IIS, might be the answer.

For example, I've modified `onUpdateRequestCache` method from code in my question to make every request go to cache:

```
private void onUpdateRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

    application.Context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public); //Location="Any"
    application.Context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1800)); //Duration="1800"
    application.Context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
}
```